# How do you best render multiple variables at the same time in Mongoose/Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I am relatively new to programming, and my first big project is creating a site using Mongoose and Node.js.

My question is how do I render two variables for ejs simultaneously, without throwing an error by attempting to render a query that has not executed completely? I will obviously explain throughout the post.

I am attempting to retrieve specific documents from my database when the home page is requested, and render them to the user using ejs, as shown by the code below:

```
let brandsToBeSent;
let postsToBeSent;
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  Category.find({categoryName: "Featured"}, function(err, featuredPosts){
    if (!err){
      Brand.find({_id: featuredPosts[0].categoryProducts}, function(error, brands){
        if (!error){
          brandsToBeSent = brands;
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
  Brand.find({}, function(err, allPosts){
    if (!err){
      postsToBeSent = allPosts;
    } else {
    console.log(err);
    }
  });

res.render("home", {featuredposts: brandsToBeSent, siteposts: postsToBeSent});

});
```

When the server is already loaded, everything works great! However, **After restarting the server (rs in the console) and reloading the page, it will pose a brief error.** I'll copy the error below:

```
TypeError: /Users/rsouthward/Desktop/Prototypev1.00/views/home.ejs:5
    3| <%-include("navbar")%>
    4| <%-include("graphics")%>
 >> 5| <%-include("featured", {featured: featuredposts})%>
    6| <%-include("products", {siteposts: siteposts})%>
    7| <%-include("scripts") %>
    8| 

/Users/rsouthward/Desktop/Prototypev1.00/views/featured.ejs:15
    13| <!-- Start -->
    14| 
 >> 15| <% featured.forEach(function(post){ %>
    16|   <% var imageconcat = "" %>
    17|   <% for (image of post.brandImageURL){ %>
    18|     <% imageconcat += image %>

Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

***However, after refreshing the page half a second later, the page renders perfectly fine.*** My guess is that because my query to retrieve 'featuredposts' is actually two nested queries, it takes longer and will execute after the query retrieving 'siteposts'. ***If this is the case, what is the best way to send everything to the client at once? Should I use async? .then() statements?***

I was reading the Mongoose docs about async, .then(), and .exec(), and I do not completely understand them, but this following code is my attempt to solve the problem, which does help whatsoever.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home", {featuredposts: brandsToBeSent, siteposts: postsToBeSent});
  Category.find({categoryName: "Featured"}).exec().then(function(featuredPosts){
    Brand.find({_id: featuredPosts[0].categoryProducts}, function(error, brands){
        brandsToBeSent = brands;
    });
  }).then(Brand.find({}).exec().then(function(allPosts){
    postsToBeSent = allPosts
  })).then(res.render("home", {featuredposts: brandsToBeSent, siteposts: postsToBeSent}))
})
```

My ejs and other server stuff seems to be fine, but let me know if I should attach any other code. This is my first stackoverflow post, so sorry if I did anything wrong and thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

using async await syntax will make things a lot easier,
also this is my first stackoverflow answer :) so ask me if anything is not clear

```
app.get("/", async function(req, res) {
  try {
    let featuredPosts = await Category.find({categoryName: "Featured"});
    let brandsToBeSent = await Brand.find(
      {_id: featuredPosts[0].categoryProducts});

    let postsToBeSent = await Brand.find({});
    res.render("home", 
      {featuredposts: brandsToBeSent, siteposts: postsToBeSent});

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }


});
```